# Unable to configure Google Cloud Pub/Sub push subscriber

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have Google Cloud project consisting of a compute engine instance which I want to configure as a push subscriber of Cloud Pub/Sub service. I have setup an apache webserver with a self-signed certificate on the instance and have also made a DNS entry (abc.mydomain.com) which points to the instance which has a static IP address. I am already a verified owner of the domain (mydomain.com) on webmasters.

Whenever I add the subscription from the Cloud console, it fails with the error: "The subscription could not be added" and does not show any other useful information.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self-signed certificates are not supported.
There are few options for you:

1. Pay for the certificate
2. Use App Engine as a proxy
3. Use pull subscriptions
4. Use App Engine Managed VM

The last one is basically a Compute Engine instance, but you will get free https connection via a subdomain of appspot.com.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any specific reason for not supporting self signed certificates ? If no, then, is there a future plan to support these ?

Comment: It's technically possible, but we don't have any plans for it. Can you file a feature request at: https://code.google.com/p/cloud-pubsub/issues/list ?

Comment: Also I just added the 4th option that I overlooked.

Comment: Thanks ! There was already a feature request (https://code.google.com/p/cloud-pubsub/issues/detail?id=23). Have voted for the same and added comments there. For now we are going with using app-engine as the proxy.

Comment: I'm encountering similar issues, also using a Let's Encrypt certificate. Not sure if it's due to the cert though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700283/invalid-push-endpoint-error-during-google-pub-sub-subscription-creation