# Does Google cloud Pub/Sub Support Letsencrypt certificates?

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

This question is a follow up to [Unable to configure Google Cloud Pub/Sub push subscriber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800269/unable-to-configure-google-cloud-pub-sub-push-subscriber)

As per the answer, self-signed certificates are not supported when using a push subscriber. Are certificates generated via letsencrypt client supported ? Is it recommended to use letsencrypt ?

Comment: Now I don't know. Did you have a chance to try it? Hopefully I will try it tomorrow, or next week and get back to you.

Comment: I finally got time to install the letsencrypt certificates for my subdomain but Pubsub is still not accepting it. @TakashiMatsuo do you have any inputs from your side ?

Comment: Sorry I haven't tested it by myself yet. However, according to https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/google-nags-me-about-the-certificate-being-self-signed/7158, it should work.

Comment: Have you verify the domain ownership on the Search Console (a.k.a. Webmaster Tools)?

Comment: @TakashiMatsuo yes I have. Also, the letsencrypt certificate is working fine for the frontend. I get no warnings accessing the site using a browser.

Comment: @sshntt are you getting the "Invalid push endpoint given" error? I'm hitting this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Sorry it took a long time, but I have verified that letsencrypt certs are working fine for this purpose.

Comment: That's great ! Can you share some steps which you took ? Letsencrypt certificates were not working for me.

Comment: On the Developers Console "Verify Domains" section, do you add your domain in the form of "https://example.com"? If so, please try this form "example.com".