# Invalid push endpoint error during Google Pub/Sub subscription creation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, lets-encrypt

I've gone through all the [prereqs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/prereqs#register) on Google's site.

1. Got and installed a SSL cert (from Let's Encrypt) on server.
2. Registered and verified the domain (yes, the https url) on Google Search Console (like https://example.org).
3. Added to the domain to my API Credential's [Domain Verification](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/domainverification).

> topic='projects/myproject/subscriptions/mytopic'
>
> sub='projecs/myproject/subscription/mysub'
>
> client.projects().topics().create(topic=topic, body={}).execute()
>
> client.projects().subscriptions().create(name=sub, body={'topic': topic, 'pushConfig': {'pushEndpoint': 'https://example.org/push-handler'}})

And I get back:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/subscriptions/mysub?alt=json returned "Invalid push endpoint given (endpoint=https://example.org/push-handler). Refer to https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/subscriber#create for more information.">

Also, I'm unable to create subscriptions from Google's Pub/Sub developer console. When I try, I get back a "Subscription cannot be added" notification. I am the full owner of this topic and project, with read and write permissions. I'm able to add pull subscriptions with no problem.

Any ideas on why? It seems like I'm not the [only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790132/does-google-cloud-pub-sub-support-letsencrypt-certificates) hitting this.

Comment: How do you authenticate your request?

Comment: Private key. It worked when creating topics, so I know the authentication to Google is working fine.

Answer (score 9):

Figured it out. I included the protocol (https://example.org) in the domain verification, instead of just example.org. It would have been nice of the domain verification tool provided some validation preventing this.

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/domainverification

Comment: Thanks for the update. So does `example.org` work? or do you need the protocol part?

Comment: Thanks! and sorry for the frustration.

Comment: NOT a fan of this domain-verification runaround.

Comment: For push, only https webhook url works. So, ensure you are giving https:// url in the endpoint.